# Chrome Dev-Tools Resume script execution

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I can get Dev-Tools to stop at a breakpoint in my JavaScript fine.  I can step into or over script fine.

What I can't seem to do is hit F8 and have the script continue as expected.
What it does is run the JS in one of my other scripts which is part of package of components (Koolajax) where it stops.

I can disable all breakpoints before I it F8 and this does work but that doesn't seem right.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Look for the pause button in dev tools and make sure it's not purple, that will let dev tools proceed with execution when there's an error

Comment: That didn't do it but I did fix it.  I unselected 'Any XHR' under XHR Breakpoints.  I have no idea what that is but it seems to work.